# How to fix the loss of transfer learning with Keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, resnet

I am doing transfer learning on a pre-trained model with an own dataset. 
Shortly, I used pretrained resnet50 model with 224x224 input shape. I am loading the model like:

```
  train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.1,rescale=1./255,preprocessing_function=preprocess_input) # set validation split

    img_size = 224

    batch_size = 32

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_size, img_size),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        color_mode='rgb',
        subset='training') # set as training data

    validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir, # same directory as training data
        target_size=(img_size, img_size),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        color_mode='rgb',
        subset='validation') # set as validation data


model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=(224,224,3))
model.load_weights("a trained model weights on 224x224")

model.layers.pop()

for layer in model.layers:
   layer.trainable = False

x = model.layers[-1].output

x = Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(101, activation='softmax', name='pred_age')(x)

top_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=predictions)

top_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer=adam,
        metrics=[accuracy])

EPOCHS = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 32
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 4424 // BATCH_SIZE
VALIDATION_STEPS = 466 // BATCH_SIZE

callbacks = [LearningRateScheduler(schedule=Schedule(EPOCHS, initial_lr=lr_rate)),
                ModelCheckpoint(str(output_dir) + "/weights.{epoch:03d}-{val_loss:.3f}-{val_age_mae:.3f}.hdf5",
                                 monitor="val_age_mae",
                                 verbose=1,
                                 save_best_only=False,
                                 mode="min")
                 ]

hist = top_model.fit_generator(generator=train_set,
                               epochs=100,
                               steps_per_epoch = 4424//32,
                               validation_data=val_set,
                               validation_steps = 466//32,
                               verbose=1,
                               callbacks=callbacks)
```

> Total params: 75,020,261
>   Trainable params: 51,432,549
>   Non-trainable params: 23,587,712
>
> Epoch 1/100
>   140/140 [==============================] - 1033s 7s/step - loss: > 14.5776 - age_mae: 12.2994 - val_loss: 15.6144 - val_age_mae: 24.8527
>
> Epoch 00001: val_age_mae improved from inf to 24.85268, saving model >
>   Epoch 2/100
>   140/140 [==============================] - 969s 7s/step - loss: 14.7104 - age_mae: 11.2545 - val_loss: 15.6462 - val_age_mae: 25.1104
>
> TEpoch 00002: val_age_mae did not improve from 24.85268
>   TEpoch 3/100
>   T140/140 [==============================] - 769s 5s/step - loss: >T14.6159 - age_mae: 13.5181 - val_loss: 15.7551 - val_age_mae: 29.4640
>
> Epoch 00003: val_age_mae did not improve from 24.85268
>   Epoch 4/100
>   140/140 [==============================] - 815s 6s/step - loss: > 14.6509 - age_mae: 13.0087 - val_loss: 15.9366 - val_age_mae: 18.3581
>   Epoch 00004: val_age_mae improved from 24.85268 to 18.35811
>   Epoch 5/100
>   140/140 [==============================] - 1059s 8s/step - loss: > > 14.3882 - age_mae: 11.8039 - val_loss: 15.6825 - val_age_mae: 24.6937
>
> Epoch 00005: val_age_mae did not improve from 18.35811
>   Epoch 6/100
>   140/140 [==============================] - 1052s 8s/step - loss: > 14.4496 - age_mae: 13.6652 - val_loss: 15.4278 - val_age_mae: 24.5045
>   Epoch 00006: val_age_mae did not improve from 18.35811

I already runned this couple times, and after epoch 4 it is not improving anymore. Also the dataset contains around 5000 images. 4511 images belonging to training set. 476 images belonging to validation set.

I get the following loss graph

[image: loss graph result]

Comment: Hard to say without the being able to run it. Could be that your validation dataset is not representative of the samples you are actually training on (unbalanced classification problem, classes present in training set not in validation set, etc..). It could also be that your model is too complex, and it is fitting the training dataset too well at the cost of generalization. If that is the case, you would need to reduce model complexity. It could even be because you forgot to shuffle your training data before partitioning it into a validation set. I would need an [mcve], but hope this helps.

Comment: I added the part above how I split the data into training and validation set. My data is just images of 101 classes.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs in pre-trained networks having BatchNormalization() and it is very stressful. Trust me! The logic being that BatchNormalization() will destroy all the trained weights if the model is not trained properly, it loses everything during back propagation.
I recommend you to try loading the model this way:

```
model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=(224,224,3))
model.trainable = False
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(224,224,3))
x = model(inputs, training=False)
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x) #if your model requires one.
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
```

and then you can add the fully connected layer of your choice and then collect the output of the entire model as follows:

```
model = keras.Model(inputs,outputs)
```

If you are looking for further explanation, I recommend you to go through this [link.](https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/guides/ipynb/transfer_learning.ipynb)

You can then continue training the model by freezing or unfreezing how many ever layers you want to, according to the dataset. Hope this helps.